# is there a loop in my logic-python

Tags: python, algorithm

I was solving the question from the website [CodeChef](https://www.codechef.com/).
I found this question:

> Some programming contest problems are really tricky: not only do they
>   require a different output format from what you might have expected,
>   but also the sample output does not show the difference. For an
>   example, let us look at permutations. A permutation of the integers 1
>   to n is an ordering of these integers. So the natural way to represent
>   a permutation is to list the integers in this order. With n = 5, a
>   permutation might look like 2, 3, 4, 5, 1.  However, there is another
>   possibility of representing a permutation: You create a list of
>   numbers where the i-th number is the position of the integer i in the
>   permutation. Let us call this second possibility an inverse
>   permutation. The inverse permutation for the sequence above is 5, 1,
>   2, 3, 4.  An ambiguous permutation is a permutation which cannot be
>   distinguished from its inverse permutation. The permutation 1, 4, 3, 2
>   for example is ambiguous, because its inverse permutation is the same.
>   To get rid of such annoying sample test cases, you have to write a
>   program which detects if a given permutation is ambiguous or not.
>
> Input Specification
>
> The input contains several test cases. The first line of each test
>   case contains an integer n (1 ≤ n ≤ 100000). Then a permutation of the
>   integers 1 to n follows in the next line. There is exactly one space
>   character between consecutive integers. You can assume that every
>   integer between 1 and n appears exactly once in the permutation.  The
>   last test case is followed by a zero.
>
> Output Specification
>
> For each test case output whether the permutation is ambiguous or not.
>   Adhere to the format shown in the sample output.
>
> Sample Input
>
> 4 1 4 3 2 5 2 3 4 5 1 1 1 0 Sample Output
>
> ambiguous not ambiguous ambiguous

I post the following python code but they said my answer is wrong 
can someone help me where is the mistake in my logic?

**my code goes here:**

```
def main():
    T=int(input())
    result=[]
    while(T!=0):
        list=[]
        list1=[]
        y=0
        value=raw_input().split(' ')
        for x in value:
            list.append(int(x))
        for x in list:
            y+=1
            x=list.index(y)+1
            list1.append(x)
        if(list==list1):
            result.append("ambiguous")
        else:
            result.append("non-ambiguous")
        T=int(input())
    for a in result:
        print a     
main()
```

Comment: You are testing for palindromes?  If so, just reverse the string and test if it's equal to the original string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this kind of things, before doubting your code it's better to double-check that the way you handle input and output match what's expected.

I know how silly you feel when you realize you fail the tests despite a correct algorithm, for something like using the string `non-ambiguous` instead of the expected `not ambiguous`.

Comment: No, you don't use the correct sentence `'non-ambiguous' != 'not ambiguous'`.

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [int(i) for i in raw_input().split()]
if arr[::] == arr[::-1]:
    print 'ambiguous'
else:
    print ' not ambiguous'
```

https://code.hackerearth.com/e29c82h